# How to implement SortedVector API using Boost library?

Tags: c++, linux, boost

I am working in a project called Rogue wave library replacement, here i need to implement functionality of RWTValSortedVector functionality using Boost library, I need to write the API for this class using Boost library code. I searched these concept in google but i didn't get proper idea about this, i spent two days in searching these things, please help me to resolve this, suggest me how to do  These two things i needed to implement it in Boost.

1. insert(const_reference a)
2. remove(const_reference a)

The reference link for RWTValSortedVector is, https://docs.roguewave.com/sourcepro/11/html/toolsref/rwtvalsortedvector.html

I need to implement this class using Boost without using the pointer, I need to insert object itself into the vector. I need to write separate .h, .cpp and main.cpp files. Looking for the better suggestions, please help.

Comment: Maybe just use a `flat_multiset`

Comment: i used multiset but unable to achieve the same functionality of RW, in RW functionality if duplicate entries exists the remove function removes only the first occurrences but here in multiset erase function will remove the all occurrences. can i achieve this using MULTIMAP?. anyone please suggest me to do this.

Comment: if you post that as a question showing the code, we can show you the trivial way to [search for the first](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/equal_range) hit and [`erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/erase) that. If you don't mind about which of the hits is erased you can gain some efficiency using [`find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/find)

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use the Boost library. The functionality you need has been in the C++ standard library since C++ was standardized.

You should be using std::vector, std::sort and std::find to implement RWTValSortedVector.

Comment: If possible can you please provide some example API or code snippets for insertion and remove operation or links related to this so that i can refer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't provide you with my implementation of RWTValSortedVector, my employer does not permit the sharing of code that they own. I can tell you that I wrote it back in 2001 using a C++98 compiler and standard library. I used a std::vector and the std::lower_bound method to find, remove and insert items. With a modern compiler and library I might do it differently.